# Stop Wordpress from setting cookie on invalid post login

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

Good day, I have a bit of code in the theme header.php file that checks to see if there is a post login cookie(wp-postpass_) and hides the header (navigation/menu) if there is no cookie(wp-postpass_). The issue is that when entering a wrong password the cookie is still generated and I have no idea why. As far as I know the code I am using is looking for a valid cookie(wp-postpass_).

Header code:

```
<!-- Check wp-postpass_ cookie and hide menu if user is not logged in -->
    <?php 
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['wp-postpass_' . COOKIEHASH];
        if (!isset( $cookie )) {
            ?>  <style type="text/css">#header {display:none !important;}</style>   <?php
        }
    ?>
```

The only other edit I did was to the post-template.php to change the look of the form with HTML:

```
function get_the_password_form( $post = 0 ) {
    $post   = get_post( $post );
    $label  = 'pwbox-' . ( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $output = '
    <div class="page-login-content">
        <div class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid full-width-section section section-no-parallax stretch" data-speed="1">
            <div class="col span_12 color-dark left">
                <div class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column column_container col no-padding color-dark">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <div class="single_image wpb_content_element align-left" data-animation="none" data-delay="0">
                            <img width="2560" height="670" src="https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-scaled.jpg" class="attachment-full" alt="esihle-banner-contact-2800" loading="lazy" srcset="
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-scaled.jpg   2560w,
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-300x79.jpg    300w,
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-1024x268.jpg 1024w,
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-768x201.jpg   768w,
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-1536x402.jpg 1536w,
                                    https://myzoladexjourney.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/esihle-banner-contact-2800-2048x536.jpg 2048w
                                "
                                sizes="(max-width: 2560px) 100vw, 2560px"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 80px"></div>
        <div class=" wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard-section section section-no-parallax stretch" data-speed="1">
            <div class="col span_12 color-dark left">
                <div class=" vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column column_container col no-padding color-dark">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element mb-0">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <h1 class="txt-white uppercase" style="text-align: center">
                                    <span class="txt-extralight letter-space-7">Welcome</span>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element">
                            <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                                <h4 class="uppercase txt-white txt-extralight letter-space-4" style="text-align: center">
                                    To the <strong>ZOLADEX</strong><sup class="h4-sup">®</sup> patient website
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 40px"></div>
        <div class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid standard-section section section-no-parallax stretch" data-speed="1">
            <div class="col span_12 color-dark left">
                <div
                    class="vc_col-sm-12 wpb_column column_container col no-padding color-dark">
                    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                        <form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" class="post-password-form d-flex flex-column align-items-center txt-center" method="post">
                        <p class="txt-center txt-white txt-light">' . __( 'This website is password protected,<br> please enter your password here:' ) . '</p>
                        <p><label for="' . $label . '">' . __( '' ) . ' <input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" /></label> <input class="login-submit" type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr_x( 'Enter', 'post password form' ) . '" /></p></form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spacer" style="height: 80px"></div>
    </div>
    ';
```

Could I potentially stop the code from creating a cookie on failed login or verify the integrity of the cookie itself within the header?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding the css rule to the if-statement in post-template.php

```
    // If post password required and it doesn't match the cookie.
    if ( post_password_required( $_post ) ) {
        ?>  <style type="text/css">#header {display:none !important;}</style>   <?php
        return get_the_password_form( $_post );
    }
```